# TextView won't setText() in ListView adapter

Tags: java, android

Fellow Overflowers,

In my project I am sending a JSON object with a name and score to a servlet, which response is a JSON list of highscores. I then convert the list to an ArrayList using GSON and set is as my hiscoreList to use in my adapter for the listview. This is all working fine except when I try to set the text for the convertView it gives a nullpointer exception.

This is my adapter code:

```
public class HighscoreAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HighscoreItem>{

    public HighscoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HighscoreItem> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final HighscoreItem item = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.highscore_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thename);
        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thescore);

        name.setText(item.getName());                        << NullPointer
        score.setText(String.valueOf(item.getScore()));      << NullPointer

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);

    ListView highscoreListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    highscoreList = new ArrayList<HighscoreItem>();

    adapter = new HighscoreAdapter(getBaseContext(), highscoreList);
    highscoreListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                sendMyScore();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How I set the list:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HighscoreItem[] highscoreItems = gson.fromJson(test, HighscoreItem[].class);

highscoreList.clear();
for(int i = 0; i < highscoreItems.length; i++){
    highscoreList.add(highscoreItems[i]);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ErrorLog:

```
06-24 22:03:39.591  15162-15162/com.example.lucschuttel.infraandsec E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lucschuttel.infraandsec, PID: 15162
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.lucschuttel.infraandsec.HighScoreActivity$HighscoreAdapter.getView(HighScoreActivity.java:82)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
```

Comment: Where is the `NPE` exactly? Post the stacktrace

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry, forgot D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thename);
TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thescore);
```

Use

```
TextView name = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.thename);
TextView score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thescore);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `convertView.findViewById(R.id.thename);` not just `findViewById`.

If that doesn't fix it please post your xml file as well.